# How to write list of tuple into CSV file?

Tags: python, csv

```
data=[('name', 'sex', 'date'), ('x1', 'f', '1948/05/28'), ('x2', 'm', '1952/03/27'),\
        ('x3', 'f', '1994/12/09'), ('x4', 'f', '1969/08/02')]
with open("g:\\test","w")  as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(data)
```

When i open g:\test file ,the format is

[image]

How can i write the data into the following format?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import csv 

data=[('name', 'sex', 'date'), ('x1', 'f', '1948/05/28'), ('x2', 'm', '1952/03/27'),\
        ('x3', 'f', '1994/12/09'), ('x4', 'f', '1969/08/02')]
with open("g:\\test","w")  as f:
    writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter=", ", lineterminator="\r\n") 
    writer.writerows(data)
```

Spot "s" at the end of `writerows`. Also, see delimiter and lineterminator arguments.

More examples [here](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#examples).

To be frank, I can't get what your problem is - values above are default, so your format should be OK...

Comment: no ,there is a new line ,i want to make every tuple in one line ,all tuples crammed together.

Comment: it is `writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter=",", lineterminator="\r\n")` not `writer=csv.writer(f, d, delimiter=", ", lineterminator="\r\n") ` .the last problem:how about if i want to add a ',' at the end of every line ?

Comment: True, my bad, I'm correcting it right now (I started typing "delimiter", checked something, forgot about "d," and typed it again :D). Also, append None at the end of each row tuple, or change lineterminator to ",\r\n".

Comment: i got it to make the ',' at the end of every line with**writer=csv.writer(f, delimiter=",", lineterminator=",\r\n")**.

Answer (score 0):

writer.writerow writes a single line. Multiple lines are written with writer.writerows. This is given in the [docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/csv.html#writer-objects).