# Sava data in a File

Tags: python, python-3.x

I need a way to save some data into a file.
They are strings.

```
# TODO: it's your job to implement this function.  You can choose an
# appropiate file format (what is important is that the dataset is
# easy to load later).  Hint: you can for instance use the csv module
# (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).
def save_data(data: DataList, file_path: str):
    """Save the given dataset in the given file."""
    pass
```

does someone know how to do it... because i tried so long but i cant do it.

whole class

```
from random import Random
from typing import Dict, List, Tuple


import os
import os.path


def read_lines(path: str) -> List[str]:
    """Return the list of lines in the file under the given path."""
    lines = []
    with open(path, 'r') as f:
        lines = f.readlines()
    return [line.strip() for line in lines]


# Some useful type aliases: languages are represented by strings,
# as well as person names.
Lang = str
Name = str


# Two different ways to represent the dataset:
#
# (a) dictionary mapping languages to the corresponding names
#     (close to the actual representation on disk)
#
# (b) list of pairs (name, language), which is the representation
#     we can actually use for training a machine learning model
#
DataDict = Dict[Lang, List[Name]]
DataList = List[Tuple[Name, Lang]]


def read_names(dir_path: str) -> DataDict:
    """
    Read the dataset in the given directory.  The result is the
    dictionary mapping languages to the corresponding person names.
    """
    data = {}
    for file_path in os.listdir(dir_path):
        full_path = os.path.join(dir_path, file_path)
        lang = os.path.splitext(file_path)[0]
        data[lang] = []
        for name in read_lines(full_path):
            data[lang].append(name)
    return data

# DataDict = Dict[Lang, List[Name]]
# DataList = List[Tuple[Name, Lang]]


# TODO: it's your job to implement this function.
def convert(data: DataDict) -> DataList:
    """
    Convert the dictionary representation to the listc
    of (name, language) pairs.
    """
    for language in data:
        name_list = data[language]
        for name in name_list:
            pair = Tuple[name, language]
            print(DataList)
            DataList.append(pair)

    return DataList


# A toy data dictionary to test our functions
data_dict = {
    "EN": ["Andrew", "Burford", "Downey", "Kilford", "Travis"],
    "DE": ["Adlersflügel", "Brahms", "Günther", "Krüger", "Schulte"]
}


# Some checks to see if conversion works as expected
data_list = convert(data_dict)
assert ('Travis', 'EN') in data_list
assert ('Schulte', 'DE') in data_list
assert ('Adlersflügel', 'EN') not in data_list


# TODO: it's your job to implement this function.
def random_split(data: list, rel_size: float) -> Tuple[list, list]:
    """
    Take a list of elements (e.g., a DataList) and divide it randomly to
    two parts, where the size of the first part should be roughly equal
    to `rel_size * len(data)`.

    Arguments:
    data: list of input elements
    rel_size: the target relative size of the first part
    """
    # Check the input argument
    assert rel_size >= 0 and rel_size <= 1

    first_data = list
    second_date = list

    for item in data:
        if Random.random() < rel_size:
            first_data.add(item)
        else:
            second_date.add(item)

    return Tuple[first_data, second_date]


# Check if random_split works as expected on the toy dataset.
(part1, part2) = random_split(data_list, rel_size=0.5)
# The length of the two parts should be the same (since rel_size=0.5)
assert len(part1) == len(part2)
# Since there are no repetitions, there should be no common elements
# in the two parts
assert not set(part1).intersection(set(part2))


# TODO: it's your job to implement this function.  Hint: you can do that
# with the help of the random_split function.
def three_way_split(data: list, dev_size: float, test_size: float) \
        -> Tuple[list, list, list]:
    """
    Take a list of elements (e.g., a DataList) and divide it randomly to
    three parts (train, dev, test), where the size of the dev part should
    be roughly equal to `dev_size * len(data)` and the size of the test part
    should be roughly equal to `test_size * len(data)`
    """
    # Check the input arguments
    assert dev_size >= 0 and test_size >= 0
    assert dev_size + test_size <= 1

    split_data = random_split(data, dev_size)
    dev_data = split_data[0]  # !!!!!
    split_data = random_split(split_data[1], test_size)
    test_data = split_data[0]
    train_data = split_data[1]

    return Tuple[train_data, dev_data, test_data]


# TODO: it's your job to implement this function.  You can choose an
# appropiate file format (what is important is that the dataset is
# easy to load later).  Hint: you can for instance use the csv module
# (https://docs.python.org/3/library/csv.html).
def save_data(data: DataList, file_path: str):
    """Save the given dataset in the given file."""
    pass


# TODO: combine the implemented functions to actually divide the dataset
# with names to three separate parts.  You can use 80% of the original
# dataset as train and 10% of the original dataset as dev.
```

Comment: Tried what, exactly? Even if it's not working, always show your attempts as well as the DataList class

Comment: i deleted it, because my prof was saying its wrong. i will upload the whole class

Comment: Thanks, but it's still not clear what you tried in the save data function

Comment: Have you seen this post? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22680722/how-to-write-list-of-tuple-into-csv-file

Answer (score 0):

Here's the relevant part from the link in the comment:

```
import csv
with open('eggs.csv', 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
    spamwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=' ',
                            quotechar='|', quoting=csv.QUOTE_MINIMAL)
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam'] * 5 + ['Baked Beans'])
    spamwriter.writerow(['Spam', 'Lovely Spam', 'Wonderful Spam'])
```

it should look roughly like this:

```
with open(file_path, 'w') as csvfile:
    writer = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=',')
    writer.writerows(data)
```